VBA Macro special pasting #VALUE! instead of the underlying Factset FDS value of the formula
When trying to paste the contents of a sheet into another workbook, the formulas aren't updating until I select an option for keeping the large amount of information on the clipboard pop-up.
I tried application.disablealerts and alsocopying a second time to get around it but it still only copies '#VALUE!' as a text and not the value of the formula or even the formula itself. i have tried various pastespecials but it is only copying the '#Value!" in every case.
Workbooks.Open Filename:=(xxxxxx), Password:="xxxxx"
Sheets("xxxxx").Activate

'Attempt to have formulas work
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True 
ActiveSheet.Calculate

Cells.Select
Selection.Copy


Windows("xxxx").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

The formulas to update before copying and for the paste to carry over the calculated value.

xlPasteValues does exactly what you describe! It calculates the formulas and paste their result. If the formula returns an error, it paste the error itself...

Please, try Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNu. If the copied formulas do not reference any cells (something as =Today() they will be copied as they are. But if they reference other cells, they will be copied with the initial reference...

There is no error on the source workbook, it only updates to reflect the value at the end but until the macro is finished it comes up with #VALUE! only.  I only get an error when changing to xlPasteFormulasAndNu.
I have tried copying the sheet entirely and then running this:
n = 0
Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone
DoEvents
n = n + 1
Loop
If n > 0 Then Debug.Print n
.      Also added in a Range().calculate. The sheet only references itself.

It should be xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats. I did not copy all the string... I tried referring to the #VALUE! string, which looks to be a formula error.

I tried that and it updates on the new sheet only when the macro is complete, but I am trying to make it static. I copied as xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats and then selected all those cell on the new sheet and tried pasting as values but get the same issue.

It works if its in another workbook alone, but this is a meaty workbook with alot of sheets and calcs and it doesn't seem to like it

I cannot get you... What do you want copying? values or formulas? Does the code using xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats correctly copy the formulas? If so, is their calculated value a correct one? If so, you should finally use ActiveSheet.Calculate followed by ActiveSheet.UsedRange.value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.value. If not, what does it copy? If difficult to explain in words, place two pictures. One of what you try copying and the second with what you obtain, mentioning the code you use...

SIde note: In general, you want to avoid using Select in your code

Im trying to copy and paste as values. It copies over fine as formulas but will say #Value! until the macro is finished. However when pasted as values, it pastes "#VALUE!" into the cell. it only does it for some of the columns and not others

Do you have Calculations set to Manual? That is why I tried the above suggestion starting with ActiveSheet.Calculate...

Its automatic, ive also set it to manual then run the calculate through the macro too. Used the side note suggestion but the same thing happens:

So I figured it out. It was the FACTSET add-in that was messing it up. They seem to store the figures outside of excel before importing it in after all processes are run - hence most formulas worked apart from all the ones referencing the FDS price cell.

So the issue is the Excel FactSet Live FDS API. The live pricing and their calculations are not running until after the macro is finished.
To solve, open the workbook via vba and run the below code. Make sure the excel project references FactSet Office API Type Library, FactSet Office API Type Library (uses FDSW32.EXE) and Factset Office API Type Library are enabled:
This will update FactSet values.
Dim FDSAPI As New FactSet_API
Dim varResult As Variant
Cells.Select
varResult = FDSAPI.RunApplication("OfficeAPI", "application=excel,method=RefreshSelectedEqualsFDS")
Calculate

You then want stop the macro and have a second macro to copy and paste using this:
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "NAME OF SECOND SUB"

This will allow the live values to refresh and update on the excel before you copy and paste. Alter the TimeValue until all values are pulled in.
